# Loaded data not showing in Pagination

Tags: flutter, api, pagination, sqflite

I used one fake API. And stored data of API in Local db.
Then first time I can show 1 to 10 data.
And then I pressed back button.
Then come into that screen again.It will show me 11 to 20 data.
Not showing 1 to 10 data.
And I want every time data from starting index.(Like 1 to Loaded Data)
I don't know why it happens !!

Comment: try out this : https://pub.dev/packages/loadmore

Answer (score 0):

every time you call an API with page number it passes data for the current page number only so you have to save old data for previous pages, or use the following package
https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination